# How wave functions overlap in STM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, microscopy

In STM(Scanning Tunnelling Microscopy), as distance between tip and sample decrease tunnelling current increases. I know that when it cross barrier wave function decay exponentially. Measured current is proportional to overlap between the wave function between tip and sample. But how does current increase when distance decreases ?. And what happens at the overlap of wave function which contribute to this increase in current ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how does current increase when distance decreases ?

The current increases exponentially with decreasing distance. This is, because the wave functions of tip and of the surface decrease exponentially into the barrier. Decreasing distance increases the overlap integral exponentially.

Mathematically, the problem can be treated in first order time-dependent perturbation theory. You assume that initially an electron occupies a particular state $\left|\left. \lambda\right>\right.$ in the tip, with an energy $E_0$ below the barrier height. Given the tunneling barrier, this state is not an eigenstate of the system and will therefore evolve in time. The rate for an electron transition into a particular state $\left|\left. \mu\right>\right.$ in the sample is then given by Fermi's Golden Rule
$$ W_{\mu,\lambda} = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\left|t_{\mu,\lambda}\right|^2\delta(\epsilon_\mu-E_0).$$
Here,
$$ t_{\mu,\lambda} = \langle\mu |H-E_0|\lambda\rangle $$
is the tunneling matrix element, and $\epsilon_\mu$ is the energy of the final state in the sample (which includes a small energy shift due to tunneling). The hamiltonian is $H=T+V(\vec{r})$ with $T$ being the kinetic energy term, and $V(\vec{r})$ describing the tunneling barrier. Working out the tunneling matrix element quantitatively depends on the exact tunneling barrier geometry, and on the wave functions in tip and sample (which depend on the materials and on geometry as well).

The exponential dependence of the tunneling current on tunneling distance stems from the exponential decay of the wave functions $\left|\left. \mu\right>\right.$ and $\left|\left. \lambda\right>\right.$ inside the tunneling barrier. Using $W_{\mu,\lambda}$ and the Fermi-distributions in tip and sample, you can work out the tunneling current by summing over the participating states.

Comment: thanx. could u pls make some insights into the mathematical description ?

Comment: @ss1729: I added a glimpse of the mathematical treatment of tunneling to give you a feeling.